# Website doesn't load embed font nor javascript, if it hasn't been loaded for a few hours

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I'm new to html/css/javascript. I just wrote [a little website](http://chiptunegenerator.com/) that usually loads normally, but sometimes, **especially if I haven't loaded it for a few hours** in a given browser, it doesn't load well in that browser: the embed font (for the title) nor the javascript (the big "play" button) load correctly. Here's [the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hjdo.png) when the problem occurs (code also copied bellow). Usually, a simple refresh (without removing cache) is sufficient to have the page correctly loaded. The two lines `wasm streaming compile failed` and `falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation` don't seem critical, since they still appear when the page correctly loads.

However, any of those messages appears in the console when I load in local. That may indicate there's problems on the server side (I'm using free Byethost hosting).

Thanks if you can help!

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://chiptunegenerator.com/Pixel.woff2
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.
falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation
failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 68 74 6d @+0
CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 68 74 6d @+0
CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 68 74 6d @+0
Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: abort(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 68 74 6d @+0). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
            at abort (http://chiptunegenerator.com/fmodstudio.js:9:16016)
            at http://chiptunegenerator.com/fmodstudio.js:9:17502
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://chiptunegenerator.com/Pixel.woff
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

Comment: This seems more like an issue with webassembly than js/html/css. Whatever wasm modules you're using to decode fonts and initialise the player are incorrectly loaded. I'm not familiar with webassembly but googling that magic word error seem to suggest that the wasm code is being read as text instead of binary.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll check that. However, any of those messages appears in the console when I load in local. That may indicate there's problems on the server side (I'm using free Byethost hosting).

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got rid of  `wasm streaming compile failed` and `falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation`by creating a .htaccess file with this inside:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType application/wasm .wasm
</IfModule>
```

However, the problem is still there: when I load the website on a browser on which it has already been loaded a few hours before, it loads with a bunch of unrelated errors, until I refresh and/or flush cache. Incomprehensible...